# Is it possible to get the event details while creating a calendar event?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to fetch event details from the Google calendar and show that on a calendar addon. I could successfully get the details of an already created event but is it possible to get the event detail, especially the title and description before it is saved on the calendar?

The below code list all the event titles and ids that are created for today and this works perfectly

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendar.calendarId).getEventsForDay(new Date()).forEach(event => {
      console.log("TITLE, ID", event.getTitle(), event.getId())
   })
```

I tried to log the event details while it is being created using the below console log

```
console.log("TITLE", CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendar.calendarId).getEventById(e.calendar.id).getTitle())
```

On the above code snippet, I get the id of the event that is being created using the `e.calendar.id` but when I pass that to the `getEventById` it returns null and the `getTitle` function fails

Is it possible to get the title and description details like this or is there any other way of getting them from the event that is being created?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When creating an event using any of the methods inside the  [CalendarApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app), the calendar Event object is returned, from which you can fetch all the things like title, description... Would this work for you?

Comment: You can call an appscript server function and have it return all of the data for you

Comment: @OriolCastander I could get the details after I create the vent. But can I get the details while the event is being created?

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. Could you please provide some references that I can check?

Comment: If you wish to be programmer you should become familiar with the documentation.  Dig in and learn it.